# How to create dynamic tabs

Tags: angular-material2

Is it possible to creating tabs on the fly? I can't use `*ngFor` and `MdTabGroup` doesn't seem to expose any collections or add methods.

Comment: See how it is done in Angular Material's [demo](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app/tabs).

Comment: @Edric: Thanks but that sample still uses ngFor approach. I need a way to add tabs using Angular Material2 api.